# Remove character from a string and list all possible permutations

Tags: python, string, permutation

I'm trying to go through a string and every time I come across an asterisk (`*`) replace it with every letter in the alphabet. Once that is done and another asterisk is hit, do the same again in both positions and so on. if possible saving these permutations to a .txt file or just printing them out. This is what I have and don't know where to go further than this:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

for i in reversed("h*l*o"):
    if i =="*":
        for j in ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
```

Right I have some more challenges for some of the solutions below that im trying to use.

1. I cannot write to a file as I just get errors.

Comment: do you want `habcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzlabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzlo` or `halao, halbo, ...` etc

Comment: Do you always have only two asterisks or can there be more?

Comment: it could be more

Comment: Some nice answers here but since OP is a beginner, would love to see one not using any libraries!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

1. [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) the amount of asterisks in the string.
2. Create the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of all letters with as many repetitions as given in (1).
3. Replace each asterisk (in order) with the matching letter:

```py
import string
import itertools

s = "h*l*o"

num_of_asterisks = s.count('*')
for prod in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=num_of_asterisks):
    it = iter(prod)
    new_s = ''.join(next(it) if c == '*' else c for c in s)
    print(new_s)
```

Notes:

1. Instead of creating a string of all letters, just use the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module.
2. This converts the product's tuples to [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) for easy handling of sequential replacing of each letter.
3. Uses the [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to create the new string out of the input string.
4. The above code simply prints each permutation. You can of course replace it with writing to a file or anything else you desire.

Comment: Wow you got almost the exact same answer as me :/

Comment: Nice idea. I used something with `s.split()` and an extra loop, but I like this more.

Comment: @Matthias would like to see your version but I can imagine what you did. `split` on the asterisk, count the number of elements in the split, and then `join` the split with the product?

Comment: @mousetail yeah sorry about that. Just a few seconds between us. You know what they say, great minds think alike ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problems. I assume you mean the cartesian product and not "permutations".

I would use itertools:

```py
string = "h*l*o"

import itertools
# for every combination of N letters
for letters in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=string.count('*')):
    # iterate over the letters
    letter_iter = iter(letters)
    # replace every * with the next instance
    print(''.join(i if i!='*' else next(letter_iter) for i in string))
```

Comment: Using this code i cannot seem to get the print output to redirect/save into a file

Comment: Simply replace `print` with whatever other function you want, like `file.write` if you want to write to a file